# trigger lazyload on hash change

Tags: lazy-loading

i have built a site using lazyload.js to fade in images when the page is visited. like so...

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    if (location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(2);
        switch (hash) {
            case "about":
                changeContent('about');
                break;
            case "contact":
                changeContent('contact');
                break;
            default:
        };

        $("img").lazyload({
            effect : "fadeIn",
        });
    } else {
    };
}
```

the site is built using various pages but i am learning about how to use location.hash to make the website work more like an app within one page.

unfortunately, when switching the code to use onHashChange, everything seems to work except the lazyload images, they remain white.

i asume this is because the page hasn't just loaded and so lazyload doesn't kick in.

can anyone offer any advice for how to create the same effect when changing content with hash changes.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the event you are using on lazy loaded image on `hashchange` event. Lazy Load default event is `scroll` and default container is `window`. You should be able to do something like:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
   $(window).trigger("scroll"); 
}
```

From your question it is not clear what `changeContent()` function does. If it loads content via AJAX|H you must also bind plugin to newly loaded content.